# Custom form not showing in correct place on page

Tags: plugins, pages, templates, page-template, forms

I have a page like this:

```
<h2 class="subHeader contentSubHeader">Are you already a member? Don´t miss your next career opportunity!</h2>
<p class="subHeader contentSubHeader">[one_half padding="0px 40px 0 20px"][multipage_form][/one_half]</p>

<div class="text contentText">
<p style="text-align: left;">[one_half_last padding="0px 20px 0 20px"]</p>
✔ We'll keep you informed about new opportunities in the digital sector that fit your profile.

✔ We have new opportunities every week in UX, e-commerce, mobile, SEO/SEA, social media, online marketing, big data, ...

✔ PPC, UX, SEO, RTB, ... . We know what you're talking about.
<p style="text-align: left;">[/one_half_last]</p>
&nbsp;
<h2 class="subHeader contentSubHeader">Get on board and join the Crew!</h2>
```

and so on ... . As you can see I output the form **multipage_form**. I've created a custom plugin `Multistep Form` where I create a form. My `multistep_form.php` in plugin **multistep_form** looks like this:

```
<?php
// Add shortcode to include form in page
// KEY, VALUE
add_shortcode('multipage_form','multipage_form');

// Register site styles and scripts is_page( 'about-me' )
/**
 * @todo: check which page, only check on /subscribe
 */
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','multistep_form_init');

// Create form
function multipage_form()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $this_page      =   $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $page           =   $_POST['page'];
    if ( $page == NULL ) {

        /**
         * first name
         * last name
         * email address
         * current job title
         * // autofill with linkedin //
         */

        // output form
        echo
        '<form method="post" action="' . $this_page .'">

            <label for="FNAME" id="FNAME">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="FNAME" id="FNAME" required="required" />

            <label for="LNAME" id="LNAME">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="LNAME" id="LNAME" required="required" />

            <label for="EMAIL" id="EMAIL">Email address: </label>
            <input type="text" name="EMAIL" id="EMAIL" required="required" />

            <label for="CURRENTJOBTITLE" id="CURRENTJOBTITLE">Current Job Title:</label>
            <input type="text" name="CURRENTJOBTITLE" id="CURRENTJOBTITLE" />

            <!-- Hidden value for page -->
            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="page" />

            <input type="submit" value="Next" />

        </form>';
    }   // END PAGE 1 FORM

    elseif ( $page == 1 ) {

        // store POST variables
        $first_name         = $_POST['FNAME'];
        $last_name          = $_POST['LNAME'];
        $email              = $_POST['EMAIL'];
        $current_jobtitle   = $_POST['CURRENTJOBTITLE'];

        // get taxonomy terms
        $years_experiences = get_taxonomy_terms('job_listing_category');
        $job_types = get_taxonomy_terms('job_listing_type');
        $job_regions = get_taxonomy_terms('job_listing_region');
        $job_tags = get_taxonomy_terms('job_listing_tag');

        /**
         * are you (freelancer, ...)
         * you live in (brussel, ...)
         * years of experience
         * expertise in digital (choose max 2: data science, e-commerce, ...)
         */

        // output form
        echo '
        <form action="' . $this_page .'" method="post">

            <label for="JOBTYPE" id="JOBTYPE">Are you...</label>
            <select name="JOBTYPE" id="JOBTYPE">
            ';
            foreach($job_types as $job_type)
            {
                echo '<option value="' . $job_type->term_id . '">' . $job_type->name . '</option>';
            }

            echo '</select>

            <label for="JOBREGION" id="JOBREGION">You live in...</label>
            <select name="JOBREGION" id="JOBREGION">
            ';
            foreach($job_regions as $job_region)
            {
                echo '<option value="' . $job_region->term_id . '">' . $job_region->name . '</option>';
            }

            echo '</select>

            <label for="YEARSEXPERIENCE" id="YEARSEXPERIENCE">Years of experience in digital:</label>
            <select name="YEARSEXPERIENCE" id="YEARSEXPERIENCE">
            ';
            foreach($years_experiences as $years_experience)
            {
                echo '<option value="' . $years_experience->term_id . '">' . $years_experience->name . '</option>';
            }

            echo '</select>

            <p>Expertise(s) in digital (choose maximum 2):</p>';

            foreach($job_tags as $job_tag)
            {
                echo '<input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="tags" value="' . $job_tag->term_id . '">' . $job_tag->name . '<br>';
            }

            // Hidden value for page
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="page" value="2" />
            <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="' . /*$form_id*/ "hello" . '" />

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

            ';
    }   // END PAGE 2 FORM
}

/**
 * @param $taxonomy_category
 * @return array
 *
 */
function get_taxonomy_terms($taxonomy_category)
{
    $args = array(
        'orderby'    => 'count',
        'hide_empty' => 0,
    );

    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy_category, $args);

    return $terms;
}

function multistep_form_init() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'multistep-form-js', plugins_url( '/js/custom.js', __FILE__ ));
}
```

Now when I check the page where my form is shown, the form is always show on top and not in `<p class="subHeader contentSubHeader"></p>` where it should be ... . My HTML looks like this after rendering the form:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <form method="post" action="/subscribe/"><label for="FNAME" id="FNAME">First Name:</label> <input type="text" name="FNAME" id="FNAME" required="required" style="cursor: auto; background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABHklEQVQ4EaVTO26DQBD1ohQWaS2lg9JybZ+AK7hNwx2oIoVf4UPQ0Lj1FdKktevIpel8AKNUkDcWMxpgSaIEaTVv3sx7uztiTdu2s/98DywOw3Dued4Who/M2aIx5lZV1aEsy0+qiwHELyi+Ytl0PQ69SxAxkWIA4RMRTdNsKE59juMcuZd6xIAFeZ6fGCdJ8kY4y7KAuTRNGd7jyEBXsdOPE3a0QGPsniOnnYMO67LgSQN9T41F2QGrQRRFCwyzoIF2qyBuKKbcOgPXdVeY9rMWgNsjf9ccYesJhk3f5dYT1HX9gR0LLQR30TnjkUEcx2uIuS4RnI+aj6sJR0AM8AaumPaM/rRehyWhXqbFAA9kh3/8/NvHxAYGAsZ/il8IalkCLBfNVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==); background-attachment: scroll; background-position: 100% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;"><label for="LNAME" id="LNAME">Last Name:</label> <input type="text" name="LNAME" id="LNAME" required="required"><label for="EMAIL" id="EMAIL">Email address: </label> <input type="text" name="EMAIL" id="EMAIL" required="required"><label for="CURRENTJOBTITLE" id="CURRENTJOBTITLE">Current Job Title:</label> <input type="text" name="CURRENTJOBTITLE" id="CURRENTJOBTITLE"> <input type="hidden" value="1" name="page"><input type="submit" value="Next"></form>

    <h2 class="subHeader contentSubHeader">Are you already a member? Don´t miss your next career opportunity!</h2>

    <p class="subHeader contentSubHeader"></p>

    <div class="content-column one_half">
        <div style="padding-top:0px;padding-right:40px;padding-left:20px;"></div>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    ....
</div>
```

As you see my form is on top and I can't explain why ... . What am I doing wrong?

[Click here for link to the page](http://www.staging.conversiontalent.eu/subscribe/).

Comment: share the link to the page

Comment: Added link to the page

Comment: Shortcode should return, not echo, and that's why it's not working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with shortcode you must return a value rather than output directly.  The below amendmetn should fix your positioning issue.

For more informaiont, see the [Shortcode API Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Output), speciffically the **Output** section.

```
function multipage_form()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $this_page      =   $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $page           =   $_POST['page'];
    if ( $page == NULL ) {

        /**
         * first name
         * last name
         * email address
         * current job title
         * // autofill with linkedin //
         */

        // output form
        $my_form = '<form method="post" action="' . $this_page .'">

            <label for="FNAME" id="FNAME">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="FNAME" id="FNAME" required="required" />

            <label for="LNAME" id="LNAME">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="LNAME" id="LNAME" required="required" />

            <label for="EMAIL" id="EMAIL">Email address: </label>
            <input type="text" name="EMAIL" id="EMAIL" required="required" />

            <label for="CURRENTJOBTITLE" id="CURRENTJOBTITLE">Current Job Title:</label>
            <input type="text" name="CURRENTJOBTITLE" id="CURRENTJOBTITLE" />

            <!-- Hidden value for page -->
            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="page" />

            <input type="submit" value="Next" />

        </form>';
    }   // END PAGE 1 FORM

    elseif ( $page == 1 ) {

        // store POST variables
        $first_name         = $_POST['FNAME'];
        $last_name          = $_POST['LNAME'];
        $email              = $_POST['EMAIL'];
        $current_jobtitle   = $_POST['CURRENTJOBTITLE'];

        // get taxonomy terms
        $years_experiences = get_taxonomy_terms('job_listing_category');
        $job_types = get_taxonomy_terms('job_listing_type');
        $job_regions = get_taxonomy_terms('job_listing_region');
        $job_tags = get_taxonomy_terms('job_listing_tag');

        /**
         * are you (freelancer, ...)
         * you live in (brussel, ...)
         * years of experience
         * expertise in digital (choose max 2: data science, e-commerce, ...)
         */

        // output form
        $my_form.= '<form action="' . $this_page .'" method="post">

            <label for="JOBTYPE" id="JOBTYPE">Are you...</label>
            <select name="JOBTYPE" id="JOBTYPE">
            ';
            foreach($job_types as $job_type)
            {
                $my_form.= '<option value="' . $job_type->term_id . '">' . $job_type->name . '</option>';
            }

            $my_form.= '</select>

            <label for="JOBREGION" id="JOBREGION">You live in...</label>
            <select name="JOBREGION" id="JOBREGION">
            ';
            foreach($job_regions as $job_region)
            {
                $my_form.= '<option value="' . $job_region->term_id . '">' . $job_region->name . '</option>';
            }

            $my_form.= '</select>

            <label for="YEARSEXPERIENCE" id="YEARSEXPERIENCE">Years of experience in digital:</label>
            <select name="YEARSEXPERIENCE" id="YEARSEXPERIENCE">
            ';
            foreach($years_experiences as $years_experience)
            {
                $my_form.= '<option value="' . $years_experience->term_id . '">' . $years_experience->name . '</option>';
            }

            $my_form.= '</select>

            <p>Expertise(s) in digital (choose maximum 2):</p>';

            foreach($job_tags as $job_tag)
            {
                $my_form.= '<input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="tags" value="' . $job_tag->term_id . '">' . $job_tag->name . '<br>';
            }

            // Hidden value for page
            $my_form.= '<input type="hidden" name="page" value="2" />
            <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="' . /*$form_id*/ "hello" . '" />

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

            ';
    }   // END PAGE 2 FORM

    return $my_form;

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Never worked with wordpress so was just trying something out :-) You're my hero of the day!